# My app crashes when i try to launch it

Tags: arrays, string, crash

My app crashes when i tried to launch it.

I'm trying to learn how to make the app cycle through an array of strings and then repeats once everything has been picked. This is done with a press of a button. But it crashes when i try to launch it on my phone. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textOne.setText(pick());
        }

        List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("b");
            add("a");
            add("z");
            add("y");
            add("x");

        }};
        List<String> dupeList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            addAll(myStrings);
        }};

        Random r = new Random();

        public String pick() {
            String retval = "";
            int pos;
            switch (dupeList.size()) {
                case 1:
                    retval = dupeList.get(0);
                    dupeList.clear();
                    dupeList.addAll(myStrings);
                    return retval;
                default:
                    pos = r.nextInt(dupeList.size());
                    retval = dupeList.get(pos);
                    dupeList.remove(pos);
                    return retval;

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//this opens another activity
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.RulesButton:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Stacktrace (Logcat)?

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: it doesn't launch at all. it just crash and says "unfortunately, app has stopped." It doesn't show the main screen of my app.

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. i just needed to change "TextView textOne...." to "final TextView textOne..." and place it below the onCreate method.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
 Button pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textOne.setText(pick());
        }

        List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            add("b");
            add("a");
            add("z");
            add("y");
            add("x");

        }};
        List<String> dupeList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
            addAll(myStrings);
        }};

        Random r = new Random();

        public String pick() {
            String retval = "";
            int pos;
            switch (dupeList.size()) {
                case 1:
                    retval = dupeList.get(0);
                    dupeList.clear();
                    dupeList.addAll(myStrings);
                    return retval;
                default:
                    pos = r.nextInt(dupeList.size());
                    retval = dupeList.get(pos);
                    dupeList.remove(pos);
                    return retval;

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//this opens another activity
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.RulesButton:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for information as you are new in Android logs will help you more.
Log will be in eclipse tool (developing tool you are using) not on your device.
Change perspective to DDMS -> Go to LogCat.
There will be error logs in it.